# How to unwrap model so its perfectly proportioned?

Tags: modeling, texturing, uv

I can tell this is a simple question but all the tutorials have not worked for my particular task.

I have some walls that Id like to apply a seamless texture to. the walls go in the x and y, some taller than others.

I want the model to unwrap in a way so it looks like it was flattened, with every wall right after the next, so when I apply a texture in an outside program, the uv will be perfectly proportioned. 
Iv'e tried marking seams but every way I try, it doesn't work right.

Is there something Im missing here?

My Model:
 [image: My Model]
How Id like the Uv to look: 
[image: Explanation]

There must be an easy way to do this I just cant find anything or I dont know what to look for Thank you very much.

Comment: Simply UV wrapping with either ABF or Conformal should do the trick. Remove all marked seams but one. And you should use Conformal method, it can give better results for non organic shapes than Angle based. Then you should get your straight mapping. In case you are still not satisfied, then you could look into the Follow Active Quads method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1:  Mark one vertical edge as Seam. In my example I added a seam on a very visible edge but ideally this seam should be placed somewhere less obvious.

2: Select all of the mesh, open the UV mapping menu and choose the Unwrap option.

3: Open the  UV/image editor window. The unwrap should look similar to the image below. This now needs to be scaled up.

[image]

4: UV Editor window, Make sure the Cursor is at the X=0 Y=0 position of the UV space. The lower left hand corner of the UV unwrap should also be at this position.

5: Change the Scaling Pivot point to be the **2D Cursor**.

6: Scale up the UV’s until the highest edges are approximately at the same level as the top of the UV space.

[image]

7: To check seams, scale etc  Add a test texture/image in the UV editor  and see how it looks on the mesh.

[image]

8: With the 2D cursor still at the lower left hand corner of the UV space scale up or down until the test texture looks correct at the seam.

[image]

Comment: Perfect, just perfect. Before you answered I ended up "projecting from view" each side of walls from the side orthographic view, then lined it all up manually.  The rest of this project will go smoother thanks to you. Very thorough answer. @3fingeredfrog