# How i fix this texture rotation in most of the mesh faces in cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

the pbr textures when rendered in cycles look rotated differently in some parts of the wall textures for example,this is a testing scene which its very empty because its a test, i am using blender 2.78a (i cannot update it T_T)its this has some thing to do with uv maps or nodes settings?

Comment: here is the file https://files.gamebanana.com/bitpit/rendertestenviroment.blend

Comment: if we are supposed to see some image textures, we can't, perhaps pack all your image textures in your file so that we can see them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have UV unwrapped and your texture looks wrong then usually best to look first at the UV unwrapping (mapping).

Before creating complicated shading node setups its often a good idea to simply check the UV mapping using one of Blenders 2 UV grid textures instead.

To do that, in the **UV editor** create a new image: **Image** > **New** > give it a name (in this example I name the new image **Grid** ) then  from the **Generated Type** menu choose either **UV Grid** or **Color Grid**

[image]

Next in the **Node editor** assign this new checker board image to your mesh.

Now lets look at your perimeter wall when it is mapped to this checker board image :

[image]

The Checkerboard texture looks rotated and differently scaled on each wall.

From your PBR node setup it looks like you are wanting to use a seamless red brick texture on this wall.

For that to work you will need to have the scaling even on each section of wall, with minimum distortions and ideally without any rotation.

The Brick texture will be aligned horizontally so you should aim to ave the UV islands of the wall also mapped horizontally.

To achieve this you will need to add few more seams so that with a new UV unwrap the perimeter wall will be   broken into 4 UV islands.

[image]

Unwrap the perimeter wall again :

[image]

The checkerboard texture is looking better but we can see in the UV editor that the uv islands are aligned vertically.

Select them all and rotate 90°.

[image]

Now you should be able to use this UV unwrap in your original PBR node setup.

It wont be perfect. I think if I were doing this I would have the tops of the walls as separate UV islands and edit those in the UV editor so that they could be mapped to a part of the red brick texture that looks like the top of a wall but I'm trying to keep this simple.

Here you will find another example of UV unwrapping a wall :
[How to unwrap model so its perfectly proportioned?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/81551/how-to-unwrap-model-so-its-perfectly-proportioned/81569#81569)

There are different ways or laying out UV's depending on what you want to do with them.

Don't worry about the perimeter wall now taking up so much more space in the UV square. It shouldn't effect what you seem to be trying to do.
The perimeter wall is using the wall1 texture and now covering 50% of the UV space.
What about all the rest of the model ? The ground (grass001 material) the buildings (wall2 material) etc etc well think of those as different layers on the same UV map.
Each material will be on its own "layer".

The UV unwrapping (mapping) work flow will be:

Select all the mesh which uses material_1 and UV unwrap that, Check the Unwrap using the grid texture and edit those Uv's as required. Laying out the islands so that they are aligned and scaled to the grid.

When you are happy with the layout of the mesh using material_1 repeat for the next material.

When you are finished, if you select all of the mesh the UV's will look a complete mess in the UV space because each material will be stacked (layered) one on top of the other in the UV space. But selecting one material at a time they should look good (understandable).

I recommend you spend a couple of hours watching YouTube videos on the different ways of UV unwrapping depending on how they will be used.

Also...............

Your L shaped building has most of its wall inside out (flipped normals)

Something to think about : I added a 1.80 meter high character to your scene, looks tiny standing beside the well. Unless you have good reason its usually a good idea to model to scale 1:1 .

[image]

Comment: Awesome question and awesome answer :) Just started using blender myself. I get the feeling after getting the basics down, it's all about tricks, cheats and buckets of gotchas to get it to look the way you want

Comment: @DerpyNerd yep thats right i am now an advanced blender user :D, good luck in your journey dude :D

Comment: Thanks! It's a bumpy road, but as soon as you find the normals it will really shine a light on the subject :D (badum tss) Anyhow, I'm doing this in my spare time so I'll wait and see how advanced I can get. Congrats on your advancements. It sounds awesome being able to create anything you want