# Unwrapping not working and not giving any error message

Tags: uv

I'm trying to apply texture to the walls of the building I got and in some faces I can unwrap images to apply the textures but in others (for example on the left side, in the bottom left face i can't unwrap the image i want to). I'm using the v2.9 of blender. I really can't understand why the unwrap doesn't work. I'm having the same issue in more figures but just showing one of them. Thanks for the help

This is the link to the blender file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MbmFUJm0iwbBOqAb7PMY-2Tjbl47F7JW/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the faces appear to be unwrapped, so I don't understand what you mean by " *on the left side, in the bottom left face i can't unwrap the image i want to* ".

There are scaling issues and it would have helped some if you had packed your image texture into the .blend file.
You have not marked any UV Seams.
You also have two UV maps for your building so you need to tell Blender which one you want to be used by adding a UV Mapping node, See screenshot below:
[image]

The usual way of unwrapping such a building would be the following:

1: Apply the Boolean modifiers.

2: Mark UV seams.
[image]

3: UV Unwrap.
[image]

4: Edit the UV's to suit the type of texturing. In the example below the UV's have been
edited for use with seamless (tilable) textures. See this earlier post for more detailed explanation on how to do this.

[How to unwrap model so its perfectly proportioned?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/81551/how-to-unwrap-model-so-its-perfectly-proportioned/81569#81569)

[image]

[image]